# Analyze JS syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to analyze a line of code written by someone else. Specifically I want to find the Javascript code that is called when the below link is clicked....

```
<a href="#subtabs_and_searchbar"  
    id="finish_counting" 
    onclick="$('#finish_counting').click();">

    <span>Submit Answer</span>
</a>
```

But as you can see they do not have the actual Javascript function name inside the onClick event listener. Can you please help me understand what is there?

Also is this syntax pure Javascript or is there something else there? Jquery perhaps?

Comment: It triggers click event on click that will probably trigger the click event ... on click

Comment: Infinite loop. Useless script.

Comment: There is jquery, he is telling jQuery: "when the user clicks that link, click the link" that doesn't make much sense, but maybe he removed the default browser behavior on click so he added it back in with this small "hack".

Comment: It's pointless. I'd start looking over everything else that this certain someone wrote.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `onclick`?

Comment: Did any of these answer your question? please accept an answer if it did. Otherwise, let us know how else we can help.

Answer (score 2):

> Specifically I want to find the Javascript code that is called when
>   the below link is clicked....

**Here it is:**

```
onclick=$('#finish_counting').click();
```

Now, this code ***might*** trigger another `click` event handler which is not shown in your post and presumably looks like this code:

```
$('#finish_counting').on('click', function(){
     //Do some handling
})
```

**UPDATE:**
Taking a further look on your code lead me to the conclusion that you're in an infinite loop - the anchor tag and the jQuery code refers to the same `ID`.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually just calling the method .click(). It is actually triggering a click event. I'm not sure why they'd want to do that, especially in the onclick attribute...but that's what this code does.

Comment: It's not triggering a click, it's creating a new click handler.

Comment: This method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler ) in the first two variations, and .trigger( "click" ) in the third. Direct quote from jQuery API docs http://api.jquery.com/click/